# Elastic-nest.Search with analyzer doesn't work.It can't detect analyzer

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using elastic with nest for c#.I create analyzers on index time but on search time they don't work.The search query returns me no documents.

Here is my class

```
public class Car {
   Text(Analyzer = "greek",SearchAnalyzer ="custom",Index = true,IncludeInAll = true)]
   public string SERVICE_DESC { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my search query

```
var response = client.Search<Cars>(n => n
   .Index(index)
   .Type(type)
   .Size(searchSize)
   .From(0)
   .TrackScores(true)
   .Query(q => q
   .Match(qs => qs.Field(fieldsForSearchList[0]).Analyzer("custom")
   .Operator(Operator.And).Query("*"+searchWord+"*"))));
```

As I mentioned I have already created the two analyzers ("greek","custom")

```
var response = client.CreateIndex(index, s => s.Settings(s1 => s1.NumberOfShards(5)
  .NumberOfReplicas(5)
  .Analysis(a => a.TokenFilters(t => t
  .IcuTransform("greeklatin", it => it.Id("Greek-Latin; NFD; [:NonspacingMark:] Remove; NFC")//
  .Drection(IcuTransformDirection.Forward)) //
  .IcuTransform("latingreek", lg => lg.Id("Greek-Latin; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC")
  .Direction(IcuTransformDirection.Reverse))
  .EdgeNGram("greekedge", ed => ed.MaxGram(50)
  .MinGram(1)
  .Side(EdgeNGramSide.Front))
  .Stop("greekstop", sw => sw.StopWords())
  .Lowercase("greeklowercase", gl => gl.Language(Language.Greek.ToString()))
  .KeywordMarker("greekkeywords", gk => gk.Keywords("")).Stemmer("greekstemmer", gs => gs.Language(Language.Greek.ToString())))
  .CharFilters(ma => ma.Mapping("hmap", map => map.Mappings("h=>η"))).Analyzers(a1 => a1.Custom("greek", t =>t.Tokenizer("standard").Filters("greekedge",/* "greekstop",*/ "greeklowercase", "greekkeywords",/*"greekstemmer",*/ "greeklatin", "latingreek")
  .CharFilters("hmap")) .Custom("custom", cu => cu.Tokenizer("standard").Filters(/*"greekstop",*/ "greeklowercase", "greekkeywords",/* "greekstemmer" ,*/ "greeklatin", "latingreek")
  .CharFilters("hmap"))))));
```

Comment: Gentle nudge: please format your code; It makes it much harder for people to help when the question and code are not presented clearly :)

Comment: What does the mapping look like in `index`? Can you add to your question what is returned when you issue `GET /{index}/_mapping`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but when you map fields in elastic it tends to lowercase their first character.For example when I used to add a field "SERVICE" it was automatically converted to "sERVICE", etc. So at least the very first character must be lowercased both on mapping and on fields declaration on our class.